# Can't render destructured title prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render Title prop in H1 tag i can see prop in React developer tools but not rendering.
[React developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glni1.png)

```
const Card = ({
  Title,
  SubTitle = '',
  Body,
}) => (
  <div className='card'>
    <div className='description'>
      <h1>{Title}</h1>
      <h2>{SubTitle}</h2>
      <p>{Body}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Card;
```

Comment: You might be mistaking in providing the value of prop. It might be some casing mistake while rendering the component

Comment: @Akhilesh why? What would that solve?

Comment: Show us how you render this component....

Comment: I would recommend debugging this manually, change the component to be a normal block function body with explicit `return` and console.log the props.

Comment: @BrianThompson Sorry about the comment above. Realized that functional components always re-render on props change.

Comment: @BrianThompson console.log(Title) => undefined, console.log(SubTitle) => ' ' as i expected, console.log(Body) => 'My favorite free resource website...'

Comment: The code that you have presented is perfectly fine. We need more context, as the error is not in the current code provided.

Answer (score -1):

it will be helpful if you paste here how you call the Card component...
anyway try this where you want to render the component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

//i suggest you to name props in camelCase (just my opinion)
const Card = ({ body, subTitle, title }: any) => (
  <div className='card'>
    <div className='description'>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <h2>{subTitle}</h2>
      <p>{body}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
)

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Card body='body text' subTitle='subtitle text' title='Title text' />
  )
}



render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.